# windows scheduler to do svn update every 1minute

Tags: svn, scheduler

How do do an update of update a svn controlled folder every minute to grab the latest repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are on windows**
Use the windows task scheduler (in the control panel) to schedule the svn.exe command line client to do a `svn update c:\workingcopy`

An alternative might be to use [SvnNotifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/) to get a tray notification when you need to do an update.

**If you are on unix/linux**
Schedule `svn update ~/workingcopy/` with [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: thanks dude! i manage to get it up with tortoiseproc.exe i will try the svnnotifier